# Get the particular key and value in angular

Tags: angular

I need help from this. how to get the particular key and value from the object.

```
    {RuleExpression: 'DEFAULTS.epHDefaults.gen== true', Action: Array(0), DefaultActions: Array(3)}
    Action: []
    DefaultActions: (3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
    RuleExpression: "DEFAULTS.epHDefaults.gen== true"
    [[Prototype]]: Object
    
    here need RuleExpression(RuleExpression: "DEFAULTS.epHDefaults.gen== true") key value from the above in angular. Please help on this
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you:

```js
const obj = { name: "My Property Name" };

for (const prop in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      console.log(prop);
      console.log(obj[prop]);

      // do stuff
  }
}
```

If you want to bind to a specific known property, just add the `if` clausule using the property name:

```js
for (const prop in obj) {
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop) && prop === "name") {
      console.log(prop);
      console.log(obj[prop]);

      // do stuff
  }
}
```